# How do I ignore part of a JSON file when parsing in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Here is an example of a JSON file I am looking at: http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Default?offset=0&limit=100

I am aiming to essentially ignore the very begining of the file and start reading from entries.

I am open to suggestions I'm quite new to xcode and have been struggling with this for a while, basically aiming to parse the json with just the character info, at the moment I seem to end up with one huge dictionary in the first slot of the array.

I have experimented with NSJSONReadingAllowFragments but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

---

edit

Hoping to clarify here as I think this is poorly worded based on feedback.

I have been able to parse various files from JSON into Objective-C using the built in NSJSON libraries. However I am having trouble with this specific JSON API. I am assuming that this is because of the 'total' value at the begining. Essentially I am just after the information that follows on from 'entries' inside the square brackets. I am specifically after the character name, level and experience values as well as the rank value.

I have previously been parsing each entry into an array, with each slot of the array containing a dictionary of values. In this case everything seems to get placed into the first array slot.

I hope this helps clarify I will provide any information or copies of my code you think would be helpful.

Comment: You're saying you just want to skip the first line?

Comment: not quite, I basically want to start from the first instance of '['

Comment: your question is poorly formatted. please, consider re-write it.

Comment: Okay I will do thanks for feedback.

Comment: Why not just parse the whole thing and ignore the one little bit you don't want?

Comment: @Hot_Licks it seems to be forcing everything into one array slot.

Comment: "entries" is an array.  You can fetch elements from there and extract the values you want.  View it as an onion -- you must peel one layer at a time.

Comment: Link shows {"error":{"code":1,"message":"Resource not found"}}

Answer (score 6):

Assumming you have `NSDictionary * myFullJSONDict` containing the full json data. You can get the entries with:

```
NSArray * entries = [myFullJSONDict objectForKey:@"entries"];
```